# ls - default arguments to save time

Tags: linux, command-line, ubuntu-10.10

How do I set `ls` so that when I type `ls` it actually runs `ls -l`.
This Sounds minor but I'm trying to save keystrokes wherever I can.  This is on Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 8):

Look up the [alias command](http://www.mediacollege.com/linux/command/alias.html).

```
alias list='ls -l'
```

If you want this to "stick" add it to your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: As mentioned in another answer, you can also create an alias called **`ls`**, to "replace" the regular `ls` shell built-in.

Comment: Thanks, I was just making it explicit that you could rename the shortcut.

Comment: Thanks! Works great...I went with alias l="ls -l" and commented out the previous "l" alias in the .bashrc file.

Answer (score 6):

The normal pattern is to have `ll` aliased to this.

In Ubuntu 10 it is already done.

Here is an extract from the default `.bashrc`:

```
# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'
```

My `.bashrc` looks like this:

```
alias   l='ls --color=always -F'
alias  ll='ls --color=always -F -lh'
alias   L='ls --color=always -F     -L'
alias  LL='ls --color=always -F -lh -L'
alias  la='ls --color=always -F        -a'
alias lla='ls --color=always -F -lh    -a'
alias  l.='ls --color=always -F        -A --ignore=\*'
alias ll.='ls --color=always -F -lh    -A --ignore=\*'
```

**Note:** changing the meaning of an existing command is considered dangerous, e.g., `alias ls='ls -l'`. It can change the behavior of (badly written, though most) scripts.

Answer (score 3):

put

```
alias ls="ls -l"
```

in your ~/.bashrc file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `alias` command.

```
alias ls="ls -l"
```

You can either type this out in a shell session, or you can put it in a file to be sourced, a good one would be `~/.bashrc`. If you run it in a shell session, the alias will exist until you exit the shell. If you put it in your a file and source it each time the shell is run (such as by simply putting it in `~/.bashrc`), the alias will be created each time you open a shell.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?